# OnClick event override

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have my custom class witch is derived from TButton:

```
TLoginResultEvent = procedure (Sender: TObject; LoginResult: boolean) of object;
TLoginButton = class(TButton)
    private
      fLogin: TLoginChooser;
      fOnClick: TLoginResultEvent;
    public
      constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
      destructor Destroy; override;

      procedure OnClickResult(Sender: TObject; LoginResult: boolean);
    published
      property Login: TLoginChooser read fLogin write fLogin;
      property OnClick: TLoginResultEvent read fOnClick write fOnClick;
  end;
```

in constructor I added:

```
constructor TLoginButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  fOnClick := OnClick;
  OnClick := OnClickResult;
end;
```

But when I click on the button it's not firing OnClickResult, what am I doing wrong? Is it possible to "override" OnClick event handler or should I hide it and make for example OnResultClick event?

Comment: >what am I doing wrong?

It happens, because actual OnClick event handler is assigned after your constructor is finished executing. In Loaded method. 

But it's far more better to override Click event of TButton, as suggested lower, instead of playing with event handlers. But if you want to assign your event handler from within the component, you should assign it after TComponent.Loaded method is executed.

Comment: Events are made to be used by the app that uses your class/component, not to be consumed by itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When writing components, you should not use the event handlers to implement custom behaviour. Instead you should override the code calling these event handlers. In this case, forget about setting `OnClick`. Instead, simply add

```
public
  procedure Click; override;
```

to your class declaration, and implement

```
procedure TLoginButton.Click;
begin
  inherited; // call the inherited Click method.
  // Do something new.
end;
```

The event handlers are there to be used by the developer *using* the component. The component writer should not use them herself.

If you want the *component user* to see a different 'OnClick' method, you have to implement this yourself, like

```
type
  TLoginResultEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; LoginResult: boolean) of object;

...

TLoginButton = class(TButton)
private
  FOnClick: TLoginResultEvent;
...
public
  procedure Click; override;
...
published
  property OnClick: TLoginResultEvent read FOnClick write FOnClick;
...

procedure TLoginButton.Click;
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(FOnClick) then
    FOnClick(Self, true); // or false...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! What about implementing LoginResult to OnClick event handler, it is possible?

Comment: Nice... Slow to answer yet again :-)