# How can I create an onclick event for Delphi TPathData in my custom TControl?

Tags: delphi, onclick, firemonkey

I have created a custom control inherited from `TControl`, using `TPathData` to create lines - it draws a custom wayfinding path for a graphical application that I'm building.  I currently have created the control and have a path which is displayed and property repaints.

The inherited properties that would provide mouse-based interaction do not work (e.g., `OnClick`, `OnMouseDown`) even though I can assign an `OnClick` event handler without runtime errors. The handler is simply never called.

My custom control is declared as:

```
TPathSegment = class (TControl)
...
```

with:

```
public
  constructor Create(ACanvas: TCanvas; AObject: TControl; listsize:int32);
  destructor Destroy; override;
  ...
  procedure Paint; override;
```

From the calling program, I create an object like this:

```
mypath := TPathSegment.Create(canvas,layout1,50);
mypath.HitTest := true;
mypath.Parent := layout1;
mypath.Onclick := MyPathOnClick;
mypath.pathThickness := 10;

mypath.AddSegment(PointF(100,150),TlineMove.mMT,'',TAlphaColorRec.Black
            ,TlineEnd.leRectangle,TAlphaColorRec.Blue,TStrokeDash.Solid);
```

I expect to be able to click on a drawn line (defined by `TPathData`) and handle an event - but I can't.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to process the click *outside* of the control, instead of having the control override the virtual `MouseClick()` or `Mouse(Down|Up)()` methods to handle the click *inside* of the control? And why are you passing a `Canvas` into the control's constructor, is your ``Paint()` drawing on that `Canvas` instead of drawing on the control's own `Canvas`?

Comment: Remy - Simple ignorance - I'm still learning Delphi after a considerable hiatus.  I'm happy to know I can and should handle these events inside the control-how do I structure the override of the MouseClick() to capture the click on my path and pass it on to an external caller?

Comment: Also - wrt the passing of theCanvas into the control's constructor I have learned that I needed to override the paint and now after a fashion I have a repaint that partially redraws but as I've learned I have to either break up the path into segments so I have control over the properties for each drawn segment (i.e., line connections and waypoints are saved as separately ForWayPointsDrawing:=canvas.savestate; Canvas.Drawpath(FpathWaypoints,1);

Comment: Read the documentation: [MouseClick](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.MouseClick), [MouseDown](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.MouseDown), [MouseUp](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.MouseUp). They provide click coordinates, convert those as needed to your paths, and then add a new event to your control, ie `OnPathClick` to give the user info about the Path that was clicked, if any. As for the `Canvas`, I still don't see why you need to pass in an external `Canvas` into the control.

Comment: @Remy - I was early on in development not able to see my drawn path on the external canvas - I also considered double buffering as a way to preserve the already drawn path - now I'm not so sure.  I'll read docs and refactor what I can as you suggest and revisit this post with results. Thx

Comment: @Remy - I have refactored my code which eliminated passing in an external canvas without any impact on drawing/visibility of the drawn path.  I believe the problem was solved (and I didn't realize it when I placed an override on the paint method).  I've read the documentation on MouseClick, MouseDown, MouseUp and attempted several approaches to override the virtual events such as: procedure MouseClick(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single); override;  to which I have added a local routine in my class but it is never entered.

Comment: Sorry to say on this point I'm a bit confused especially since I've also attempted the approach recommended in this post to the best of my ability: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020534/onclick-event-override which I've been unable to capture the mouse.  I guess a little additional guidance is needed.

Comment: If your control is not calling the virtual methods, then something else in your project is likely intercepting the mouse activity before it can reach your control. I don't know any other reason for the methods to not be called otherwise.

Comment: @Remy - Thanks for your help!  I have to reconsider what's happening and potential refactor some more

Comment: @Remy - I've concluded I don't know how to implement your advice to process the mouse click or mouse down inside my control.  Can you please give me a start?  Many thanks!

Comment: you are just going to have to debug your project, and trace through the FMX source code to follow where mouse events are going and why they are not reaching your control

Comment: Ah yes - there is no magic is there?  Thanks I'm on it.

Comment: @Remy - Successful debug and implementation of your suggested approach.  The major realization was that TPathData is derived from TObject which does not include onclick, mousedown, mouseup methods.  But by including a TRectangle (with a TAlphaColorRec.null to be invisible) as a bounding box sized to the bounds reported by the TPathData enabled me to create the handler to process the clicks and do some math on the line segments to produce a new method of OnPathClick to report the segment click upon.  Since this is my first post, what should I clean up and upvote to close out this request?